# Reusing subpattern in regular expression

Tags: java, c#, regex

I have string like "operand sign operand". And pattern `(?<operand>.* ([+|-] ?<operand>.*)*)`.
Operand is more complicated then ".*". Can I put link to the first operand pattern to another side of sign to match them both. I can copy/paste it, but it seems as bad practice.
Sorry for my poor English :|

Comment: You can use groups and back-references for that.

Comment: sorry, i can't understand your question.

Comment: Are you trying to recurse the pattern or asking if copy-paste works?

Answer (score 0):

You could just make constants for your building blocks of the Regex and "build" your pattern from there. E.g. in Java:

```
final String OPERAND = "?<operand>.*";
final String SIGN = "[+|-]";
String pattern = "(" + OPERAND + " (" + SIGN + " " + OPERAND + ")*)";
```